# remove content between tags in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, wikipedia

I was trying to clean up wikitext. Specifically I was trying to remove all the `{{.....}}` and `<..>...</..>` in the wikitext. For example, for this wikitext:

> "{{Infobox UK place\n|country = England\n|official_name =
>   Morcombelake\n|static_image_name = Morecombelake from Golden Cap -
>   geograph.org.uk - 1184424.jpg\n|static_image_caption = Morcombelake as
>   seen from Golden Cap\n|coordinates =
>   {{coord|50.74361|-2.85153|display=inline,title}}\n|map_type =
>   Dorset\n|population = \n|population_ref = \n|shire_district = [[West
>   Dorset]]\n|shire_county = [[Dorset]]\n|region = South West
>   England\n|constituency_westminster = West Dorset\n|post_town =
>   \n|postcode_district = \n|postcode_area = DT\n|os_grid_reference =
>   SY405938\n|website = \n}}\n'''Morcombelake''' (also spelled
>   '''Morecombelake''') is a small village near [[Bridport]] in
>   [[Dorset]], [[England]], within the ancient parish of [[Whitchurch
>   Canonicorum]]. [[Golden Cap]], part of the [[Jurassic Coast]] World
>   Heritage Site, is nearby.{{cite
>   web|url=http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/golden-cap/|title=Golden
>   Cap|publisher=National Trust|accessdate=2014-05-04}}\n\n==
>   References ==\n{{reflist}}\n\n{{West
>   Dorset}}\n\n\n{{Dorset-geo-stub}}\n[[Category:Villages in
>   Dorset]]\n\n== External Links
>   ==\n\n*[http://www.goldencapteamofchurches.org.uk/morcombelakechurch.html
>   Parish Church of St Gabriel]\n\n"

How can I use regular expressions in python to produce output like this:

> \n'''Morcombelake''' (also spelled '''Morecombelake''') is a small
>   village near [[Bridport]] in [[Dorset]], [[England]], within the
>   ancient parish of [[Whitchurch Canonicorum]]. [[Golden Cap]], part of
>   the [[Jurassic Coast]] World Heritage Site, is nearby.\n\n==
>   References ==\n\n\n\n\n\n\n[[Category:Villages in Dorset]]\n\n==
>   External Links
>   ==\n\n*[http://www.goldencapteamofchurches.org.uk/morcombelakechurch.html
>   Parish Church of St Gabriel]\n\n

Comment: You can use 'sub' method in re module to remove those you dont want in your string.

Comment: What's this last part you're referring to 'and "....."' ?

Comment: Give a plain sample and expected output ... your question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

As the tags are nested into each other, you can find and remove them in a loop:

```
n = 1
while n > 0:
    s, n = re.subn('{{(?!{)(?:(?!{{).)*?}}|<[^<]*?>', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

`s` is a string containing the wikitext.

There are no the `<...>` tags in your example, but they should be removed as well.